# Is it possible to batch API calls to Gigya getUserInfo?

Tags: gigya

I have a script which is retrieving user info for a set of users in our account. First we're calling socialize.exportUsers to get all UIDs, then I'd like to retrieve user info for a subset of this. Currently I'm calling socialize.getUserInfo on each UID I want to retrieve, which is quite slow.

I'm wondering if there's a way to batch API calls together so I can retrieve user info for multiple UIDs with one call. I didn't find anything in their [API documentation](http://developers.gigya.com/037_API_reference) or [Developer's Guide](http://developers.gigya.com/010_Developer_Guide).

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Gigya does not currently not have API functionality that would allow you to retrieve user information back as a batch.

However, if you have an active contract with Gigya, then you should be able to contact Gigya support directly and request a user export.   Gigya has an internal data migration process where they can extract all the users on an API key into a JSON file and then send you that file.